# What accessiblity software (screen readers) is for windows?

Tags: software-rec, accessibility

What accessiblity software (screen readers) is for windows that's cheap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See wikipedia for [Comparison of screen readers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screen_readers).

It contains a long list of contemporary screen readers with their supported platforms and their licenses, which you can analyze according to your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

[Narrator](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/narrator.aspx) is present in Windows XP on up.

```
start>run narrator
```

There is also the [NonVisual Desktop Access](http://www.nvda-project.org/) project which is open source and rapidly developing.

Comment: NVDA (Non Visual Desktop Access) is a very popular free screen reader. It's simple, but good enough for many tasks.
Narrator is very limited and really just for emergencies (e.g. if a blind person works on someone else's PC where no screen reader is installed). You can use "Windows-key + U" to start the Utility Manager, which will launch Narrator (this works at login screen too!).

Comment: @ssollinger, I agree NVDA http://www.nvda-project.org/ is nice. But it's hard to read the OPs mind as to what the problem space is, and so I posted the most trivial obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Vista and above there is screen reader included in basic installation.

Answer (score 0):

have a look **[CoolReader 2](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm)**, not exactly a screen reader but it will read documents (txt, rtf, doc, html, fb2) and easily export as MP3 if needed.

CR2 works fine with Vista/Windows7.

*CoolReader 2 is freeware and portable, no installation required.*