# Usage statistics for accessiblity software (screen readers)

Tags: accessibility, screen-reader

I [asked a question earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/59160/what-accessiblity-software-screen-readers-is-for-windows/59167#59167) about what cheap/free screen reader software was available, but now I am curious as to the usages statistics of all available (not just free) screen reading software.   Is there any place that compiles this data?

My concern is that while there are some up-and-coming free software available, that not many people are using it.  I'm trying to see if there's a justification for buying an expensive software package or if using a free software package is "good enough" to test our web site accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here there may be some stats you are looking for:

[http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey/)

Comment: The link initially given goes directly to a certain section, which did not pertain to my question, but if I scrolled to the top, the question was a bit better answered, could u remove the #websites from your URL?

Comment: Removed the anchor #websites as requested from the URL

Comment: 2014 version: http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey5/

Comment: And the 2015 version, in which it is revealed that the prior surveys probably suffered from severe sampling bias: http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/